# base64_encode in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to add the following hyperlink to an email. This link will direct a user to access a dynamic sales order. It works when its listed on a webpage but not within an email.

This works when listed on my page:

```
$str = '[INVOICENO] =' . $OrderNumber . '';

echo ' <a href="http://n-server/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/NTLM/1/Integration?p=RLV&fc=de9766b2-4d43-4b93-b55d-0afac57bf79b&q=' . base64_encode ( $str ) . '">$OrderNumber</a> ';
```

Now i'm trying to send the same link within an email

```
$str = '[INVOICENO] =' . $OrderNumber . '';

$email_message = '
<a href="http://n-server/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/NTLM/1/Integration?p=RLV&fc=de9766b2-4d43-4b93-b55d-0afac57bf79b&q=' . base64_encode ( $str ) . '">$OrderNumber</a>


';
```

Is there an issue with using base64_encode within an email?

I tried to turn it into a variable and that still didnt work either.

Any ideas?

Update:

The problem is the link is broken within an email.

This is an example of the link when its echo'd on a webpage:

http://n-server/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/Client/Result?fc=de9766b2-4d43-4b93-b55d-0afac57bf79b&q=%5BINVOICENO%5D%20%3D3846411&displayOneDoc=False&orgId=1

This is an example of the link when its within an email:

http://n-server/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/Client/Result?fc=de9766b2-4d43-4b93-b55d-0afac57bf79b&q=                     3846411&displayOneDoc=False&orgId=1

Comment: you haven't actually told us the problem.

Comment: the code you showed us is fine. the error is somewhere else. "it's not working" is the absolute least helpful thing you could say. explain what exactly isn't working and post the full code.

Comment: trim it up and you'll be fine. use: `trim(base64_encode ( $str ))` in your link.

Comment: can i use that within an email or do i have to put it within a variable first?

Comment: wouldn't hurt to url encde it either `urlencode(trim(base64_encode ( $str )))`

Comment: you don't need to put it in a variable.

Comment: hint: use url_encode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [urlencode php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page

```
urlencode(trim(base64_encode($str)))
```

UPDATE 1:

```
<li> 
 <strong>View Order:</strong>

<a href='nserver2/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/NTLM/1/<?php echo urlencode(trim(base64_encode ("INVOICENO=". $OrderNumber))); ?>'> <?php echo $OrderNumber ?></a>

</li>
```

UPDATE 2:

```
    <?php

    $OrderNumber='123';  //ASSUMPTION

    $str = '[INVOICENO] ='.$OrderNumber;

    $final_string = urlencode(trim(base64_encode ($str))); 

    $email_message = '
    <a href="http://n-server/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/NTLM/1/Integration?p=RLV&fc=de9766b2-4d43-4b93-b55d-0afac57bf79b&q='.$final_string.' "> '.$OrderNumber.'</a>';

    ?>

    <li> <strong>View Order:</strong>
    <?php echo $email_message; ?>
    </li>
```

Comment: <li> <strong>View Order:</strong>  <a href='http://nserver2/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/NTLM/1/Integration?p=RLV&fc=de9766b2-4d43-4b93-b55d-0afac57bf79b&q=' ". urlencode(trim(base64_encode ( "[INVOICENO] ='" ."". $OrderNumber ))) . "'>$OrderNumber</a> </li>                                                     I'm still missing a big piece of the URL with this code

Comment: <li> <strong>View Order:</strong>
try this one   <a href='nserver2/nameofsoftware/PlatformRO/WebClient/NTLM/1/<?php echo urlencode(trim(base64_encode ("INVOICENO=". $OrderNumber))); ?>'> <?php echo $OrderNumber ?></a>
 </li>

Answer (score 0):

Try to use urlencode and urldecode for the base64_encode value due to it would be some = in base64_encode.